# (Android) How to download an image/gif without a black background?

Tags: android, background, transparent

I am using Glide to get an image as a byte array as such

```
Glide.with(context)
    .as(byte[].class)
    .load(url)
    .submit()
    .get();
```

and it works well with an image with a background, as well as GIFs. However, when there is a static image with a transparent background (.PNG), it will produce a black background instead of keeping its transparency. I know you can avoid this problem by using a bitmap, but I want to retain both .PNG and .GIF files. Is there a possible way to retain the transparent background when loading a byte array using Glide?